# Javascript get path after valid file name (like PHP PATH_INFO)

Tags: javascript

Let's assume I have page "example.com/page.php" where you can change the content by navigating to "example.com/page.php/some/other/content".

In PHP I would use the $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] variable to get the "/some/other/content" part of the url.

I now want to build a page where the page is only loaded once and Javascript does the rest.

How can I get the "/some/other/content/" part from the url with javascript?
I'm aware that I could use some string manipulation with the known file extension "php". But I was wondering if there is some built-in functionality that is always able to do this with any file extension.

I couldn't find anything about this as I'm always directed to posts about the PHP function pathinfo().

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `window.location.href` gives you the current URL, which you can then parse with string-manipulation functions according to your needs

Comment: @robinzigmond Thank you. I know about that property but wondered, if there maybe was a built-in function for what I need.

Comment: 'window.location.pathname' returns the path and filename of the current page. This means the filename is included as well as /some/other/content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems like there's no built-in solution I came up with this function. I post it in case somebody else needs it:

```
function getPathPosition(url){
//path/without/host/page.html/some/other/content
let dirs = url.split("/");
let fileFound = false;
dirs = dirs.filter((item)=>{
    if(!fileFound && item.includes(".")){
        fileFound = true;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return fileFound;
    }
});

return "/" + dirs.join("/");
}
```

This works under the following conditions:

- The file has a dot in it (so it probably has an extension too).
- The host is already removed
- The query and hash parts of the url are already removed

Answer (score 1):

This is most basic sample how to get that part of url, you can find more samples online.

```js
var url = "https://example.com/page.php/some/other/content";

console.log(url.split('php')[1]);
```

Comment: I was looking for some built-in functionality that always provides that part of the url regardless of the file extension. I'll edit my question to reflect that. But still thank you for the answer.